# newdata and several factors with different number of levels

Tags: r, dataframe, r-factor

I need to create newdata with data.frame function in R (this newdata is then used with predict-function). I have two factors to be included into newdata, but they have different number of levels. Factor SSD has 3 levels and factor Year has 4 levels. I used a following command:

```
newdata <- data.frame(
                 a = rep(mean(Data$a), 100),
                 b = rep(seq(from = min(Data$b), to = max(Data$b),
                         length.out = 100)),
                 c = rep(mean(Data$c), 100),
                 d = rep(mean(Data$d), 100),
                 SSD = factor(rep(1:3, each = 100), 
                              levels = 1:3, labels = levels(Data$SSD)),
                 Year = factor(rep(1:4, each = 100), 
                               levels = 1:4, labels = levels(Data$Year)))
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
Error in data.frame(a = rep(mean(Data$a), 100), b = rep(seq(from = min(Data$b),: 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 100, 300, 400
```

My question is: how can I create newdata with two factors with different number of levels?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `gl` to create factor:

```
data.frame(SSD =gl(3,100/3),
           Year=gl(4,100/4))
```